# Is it possible to control a 5 DOF manipulator in the 6 DOF Task Space?

Tags: control, dynamics, manipulator

I am referring to pre-computed torque control techniques that are based on the Task Space dynamic model.

Maybe by using pseudo-inverse for the Jacobian and the task space inertia matrix ?

Cheers,
Titouan

Comment: @PeterCorke maybe ?

Comment: I don't think there is any software/control technique that will add a degree of freedom missing from the mechanical structure.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat awkwardly worded question, hopefully I'm getting at the essence of what you're trying to ask here.

In short, no, you can't because with 5 DOF, you won't be able to apply force/move the end effector of the robot in any arbitrary combination of directions.

However, it might be okay that you only have 5 DOF **if** the motions that you need to do also only have 5 DOF. (eg. only motions in x, y, z and rotation in the x and z dimensions)